# Defining an interpreter for the free monad

Tags: purescript, free-monad

In the `purescript-free` package, there is a code example defining this interpreter:

```
teletypeN :: forall eff. NaturalTransformation TeletypeF (Eff (console :: CONSOLE | eff))
teletypeN (PutStrLn s a) = const a <$> log s
teletypeN (GetLine k) = pure (k "fake input")
```

How can I define and run another interpreter where the return type is `Array Int` or `State String Int`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't interpret to a specific value, as interpreters are provided as natural transformations - `forall a. f a -> g a`. The `a` here can't be "touched" by the function that is doing the interpretation.

You could interpret to `Array` or `State String`, but the `a` will always be determined by the structure you're interpreting. If you know that you only want to interpret `Free MyAlgebra Int -> Array Int` then this will all work out anyway.

Comment: How would you write an interpreter that count the number of elements? `pure 0` cannot be expressed for any `a`.

Comment: Interpret using `Writer (Sum Int)`.

Comment: Thanks. I think you mean `Writer (Additive Int)`.